# Content change via URL parameter

Tags: html, url, url-rewriting, html-injections

I have a website where I want to provide people with specific coupon links.
For example, this is the URL of my website:

```
abc.com/productID
```

I want to dynamically change the text on this page to something like this:

`abc.com/productID?CodeCuponProd="Bla Bla"`

Can this be done via the URL?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with [history.replaceState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState).

in your exemple it is :

```js
let url = "https://example.com/productID";

history.replaceState(null, null, url + '?CodeCuponProd="Bla Bla"');
```